# I get this error when a form is called up Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in

Tags: php

I get this error when ever i try to call up a form Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\civildefenceacademy\studentmanagement\qualifications_table.php on line 13... below is the line of code it is pointing to

```
<?php include('dbcon.php'); ?>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table" id="">
        <thead>
        <tr>
                    <th>Institution</th>
                    <th>Course</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th class="empty"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        ***$student_query = $mysqli->query("select * from student order by student_id DESC")or die(mysql_error());***
        $student_row = $member_query->fetch_array();
        $student_id = $student_row['student_id'];
        $query = $mysqli->query("select * from dependents where student_id = '$member_id'") or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
        $id = $row['qualification_id'];
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['institution']; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row['course']; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row['year']; ?></td> 
        <td class="empty" width=""><a href="delete_dependent.php<?php echo '?id='.$id; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Delete</a></td>


        </tr>
    <?php } ?>    

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Is the mysqli_* library successfully inclueded to your php configuration? What does `phpinfo();` tell you?

Comment: `***$student_query` are you sure its valid variable name :D

Comment: how do i check that. am new to php?

Comment: I would assume that the `***` was only to point out which part of the code the thread owner suspect to be failing :)
Umar, create a new `php file` and add `<?php phpinfo();?>` and then execute the file in your browser. See, what is stated about the `mysqli extension`.

Comment: ok.. should i place the file in my root folder?

Comment: `$student_query = ` followed by `$member_query->`? Are you **SURE** that your db connection succeeded? The error suggests that it's a boolean false, indicating failure.

Comment: yes. the db connection was successful

Comment: No matter what, according to PHP `$msqli` has not been defined anywhere yet. Or at least not as an `object` with `query()` function.